# How do I append to a RandomAccessFile? Every time I run this code, the data get overwritten

Tags: java

**How do I append data with this snippet of code? Data is always being overwritten each time I run the code.**

```
    try{
        RandomAccessFile fileWriter = new RandomAccessFile("Officers.txt", "rw");

        fileWriter.writeUTF(officerObject.getOfficerBadgeNum());
        fileWriter.writeUTF(officerObject.getOfficerFirstName());
        fileWriter.writeUTF(officerObject.getOfficerLastName());
        fileWriter.writeUTF(officerObject.getOfficerPrecint());

        fileWriter.close();
        System.out.println("Data Successfully Saved");
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error in File. Could not SAVE Officer");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Before you write, [`seek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek(long)) to the end of the file; first call [`length`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#length()). I'd also prefer a [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Like,

```
try (RandomAccessFile fileWriter = new RandomAccessFile("Officers.txt", "rw")) {
    fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length());
    fileWriter.writeUTF(officerObject.getOfficerBadgeNum());
    fileWriter.writeUTF(officerObject.getOfficerFirstName());
    fileWriter.writeUTF(officerObject.getOfficerLastName());
    fileWriter.writeUTF(officerObject.getOfficerPrecint());
    System.out.println("Data Successfully Saved");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error writing File. Could not SAVE Officer");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The point of a RandomAccessFile is to *access* data at *random* positions within the file. To enable that, there is an internal pointer that determines where the next bytes will be written to. That pointer defaults to 0.

So, as others have written, you first have to *seek* the end of the file; otherwise your writes go to the **beginning** of that file.

But the real point here: depending on your requirements, you might **not** need to use a RandomAccessFile. A simple FileWriter would do the job (when you only want to append to that file). Of course, when your primary requirement is to do "easy" UTF8 writing, then RandomAccessFile can be your first choice.

You see, when creating an ordinary FileWriter object, there is a boolean flag that determines whether the FileWriter should create a new file or append to an existing one.

Comment: I would appreciate a comment on the downvote, as I really fail to see the problem with my answer.

Comment: Agreed but if he uses a `FileWriter` he can't use `writeUTF()`.

Comment: `FileWriter` is almost always the _wrong_ choice, because it _always_ uses default encoding. Also, note that `writeUTF` doesn't simply write a string as UTF-8; it prepends the string's length; the equivalent operation would be `DataOutputStream.writeUTF`.

Comment: Thanks. Those explanations make much more sense than that uncommented downvote. Will probably enhance the answer later on.

Answer (score 0):

Add skipBytes() to go to the end of the file as below

Try as following :

```
RandomAccessFile fileWriter = new RandomAccessFile("Officers.txt", "rw");

        fileWriter.writeUTF(officerObject.getOfficerBadgeNum());
fileWriter.skipBytes( (int)fileWriter.length() );
        fileWriter.writeUTF(officerObject.getOfficerFirstName());
.
.
```